# Calculate a polygon around a point - and conver to WKT

Tags: r

The use case I have is this: I want to take points (in my case a `data.frame` of lat/long coordinates) and calculate a polygon around each point of a given radius (in km, miles, whatever). To be clear, not a polygon around all points at once, but a polygon around each point separately. This seems like it would be straightforward, but how does one do this in R?

The next thing I want to do is take those polygons and get well-known text (WKT) polygons because the web API I am querying against wants WKT. I think I can get a WKT polygon using `rgeos` like

```
library(rgeos)
g3 <- readWKT("POLYGON((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1),(2 2,2 3,3 3,3 2,2 2))")
writeWKT(g3)

[1] "POLYGON ((1.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000, 1.0000000000000000 5.0000000000000000, 5.0000000000000000 5.0000000000000000, 5.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000, 1.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000), (2.0000000000000000 2.0000000000000000, 3.0000000000000000 2.0000000000000000, 3.0000000000000000 3.0000000000000000, 2.0000000000000000 3.0000000000000000, 2.0000000000000000 2.0000000000000000))"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a data frame of lat, lon, and some ID variable. Convert to a SpatialPointsDataFrame, and give it the usual lat-long coordinate system code:

```
require(sp)
require(rgeos)
d=data.frame(lat=c(33.95,34.95,34.70), lon=c(-118.40,-118.22,-118.43),ID=1:3)
coordinates(d)=~lon+lat
proj4string(d)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

Now do the buffering:

```
 buf = gBuffer(d,width=0.2)
 plot(buf)
```

Extract the parts and convert to WKT:

```
writeWKT(buf[1])
[1] "POLYGON ((-117.4000000000000057 33.9500000000000028, -117.4489434799999970 33.6409830099999994, -117.5909830100000022 33.3622147499999997, -117.8122147499999954 33.1409830099999994, .....
```

Note this has done the buffering for all three points in the data frame, but you can only do that if you want the same buffer size for each point. I think the rgeos guys might be working on a new version where the buffer size can be a vector, for example another column in the data frame, and so different for each point.

I'll repeat the warning about working with lat-long as if it was cartesian - use `spTransform` to convert to metres using a locally cartesian coordinate system such as a UTM zone. If you really need to do this on great circle distances then `rgeos`, and `GEOS` in particular, probably won't help you.

Comment: I just started playing with gBuffer. I am running your code, but I receive the following error message. `Error: is.logical(byid) is not TRUE`. Would you mind if I ask you what causes this error? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Create a reproducible example and post it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am happy to create an example. But, your code above does not work for me although I uploaded `sp` and `rgeos`. Would you mind if I ask you to run the code on your machine and see if it works or not?

Comment: agh! they changed the args for gBuffer, you now have to spell it out unless you also want `byid=TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this does what I want:

```
library(rgeos)
foo <- function(lat, lon, ...)
{
  latlon <- paste(lon, lat)
  poly <- readWKT(sprintf("POLYGON((%s,%s,%s,%s))", latlon,latlon,latlon,latlon))
  g <- gBuffer(poly, ...)
  writeWKT(g)
}

foo(lat=33.95, lon=-118.40, width=0.2)

[1] "POLYGON ((-118.2000000000000028 33.9500000000000028, -118.2097887000000043 33.8881966000000006, -118.2381965999999949 33.8324429500000008, -118.2824429500000036 33.7881965999999991, -118.3381966000000034 33.7597887000000014, -118.4000000000000057 33.7500000000000000, -118.4618033999999938 33.7597887000000014, -118.5175570499999935 33.7881965999999991, -118.5618034000000023 33.8324429500000008, -118.5902113000000071 33.8881966000000006, -118.5999999999999943 33.9500000000000028, -118.5902113000000071 34.0118033999999980, -118.5618034000000023 34.0675570499999978, -118.5175570499999935 34.1118033999999994, -118.4618033999999938 34.1402112999999972, -118.4000000000000057 34.1499999999999986, -118.3381966000000034 34.1402112999999972, -118.2824429500000036 34.1118033999999994, -118.2381965999999949 34.0675570499999978, -118.2097887000000043 34.0118033999999980, -118.2000000000000028 33.9500000000000028))"
```

It's sort of cheating I guess since I'm creating polygon with all four corners the same exact point, then use `gBuffer` to make a wider polygon of width `width`, then write a WKT polygon

Thanks to Simon Goring for the help (https://twitter.com/sjGoring/status/408458101252030464)

Comment: Can't you use `gBuffer` on SpatialPoint objects to get circular polygon buffers? Also, you need to be very careful with mixing lat-long coordinates with anything you think is a 'distance'. For a small region, convert to a cartesian coordinate reference system first.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply on this, Thanks for pointing that out